# Using the gpgme library from .NET?

Tags: .net, gnupg, gpgme

This question is actually two questions:

1. How to use the [gpgme](http://www.gnupg.org/gpgme.html) library in Windows?
2. Are there bindings for .NET available somewhere? (If not, I guess I can make my own.)

EDIT: Solution found: [gpgme-sharp](https://github.com/gpgme-sharp/gpgme-sharp) works very nicely both in Linux and Windows. (For the latter, the only prerequisite is [gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org/download.html) which includes the gpgme DLL.) Be sure to look at the GpgmeSamples solution in the Samples subdirectory.

That library deserves some love. I recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gpgme-sharp](https://github.com/gpgme-sharp/gpgme-sharp) contains .NET bindings to the library.

Comment: You could always make your own... or even better, start with his code and improve upon it :)

Comment: Neither of the links above are currently working. Found this: [https://github.com/danm-de/gpgme-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/gpgme-sharp)

Comment: I just updated this library to support .NET Core, and published it to NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/gpgme-sharp

Comment: looks like all links are dead, the code can be found here: https://github.com/gpgme-sharp/gpgme-sharp

Comment: @thatOneGuy thanks just fixed the link.