# link to gpgme library in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, gpgme

I found this old post:

[Using the gpgme library from .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156819/using-the-gpgme-library-from-net)

but it can't help me to link my C++ project (Visual Studio) to libgpgme-11.dll.

I am using Windows 10 platform, and have done the followings to try to set it up:

Properties->Linker->Input: **libgpgme-11.dll**
Properties->Linker->Additional Library Directories: **Gpg4win\lib** and **Gpg4win\bin_64**
Properties->C/C++ General->Additional Include Directories: **Gpg4win\include**

When I compiled the project, I got an Link error LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: can not read at 0x368.

It seems to me that the libgpgme-11.dll is not the correct one to link against. Yet, I don't find any gpgme lib files under the root Gpg4win folder.

Any recommendation ?

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things to do in setting gpgme in Visual Studio:

1. Add "Gpg4win\include" to the "Additional Include Directories" property
2. Add "Gpg4win\bin and Gpg4win\lib" to the "Additional Library Directories" property
3. Add "**libgpgme.imp**" to the "Additional Dependencies" property

The Additional Library Directories and Additional Dependencies properties are under Linker's **General** and **Input** tabs. The Additional Include Directories property is under C/C++ **General** tab.

Hope this saves someone else's time.